# Unknown IP/ISATAP connection

Tags: windows, router, ip, firewall

Lately I have seen these suspicious entries in my Norton firewall log:

[image]

First entry:

> 2017-06-07 20:00:33,Info,"Protecting your connection to a newly detected network on adapter \"Microsoft ISATAP Adapter\" (IP address: fe80::5efe:192.168.0.10%13)."

Second entry:

> 2017-06-07 20:30:17,Info,IP address has disappeared from adapter Microsoft ISATAP Adapter (IP address: fe80::5efe:192.168.0.10%13).
>   IP address has disappeared from adapter Microsoft ISATAP Adapter (IP address: fe80::5efe:192.168.0.10%13). "

What is this?
I have a computer that is connected to a router and then I have a laptop that have a wirelss connection. I see entries like these on both computers and
I can ping 192.168.0.10%13 in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

ISATAP is a method of providing "overlay" IPv6 access to an otherwise IPv4-only network. For this, Windows creates a virtual "ISATAP tunnel adapter" with addresses based on all your physical LAN IPv4 addresses.

For example, `192.168.0.10` (v4) → `fe80::5efe:192.168.0.10` (v6), which is shown in mixed format but can also be written as `fe80::5efe:c0a8:000a` in native format.

(The `%13` is a "zone index", i.e. network adapter ID, used for link-local `fe80:…` addresses only.)

---

This is normal Windows behavior.

Since your network doesn't support ISATAP (if it did, you'd see global addresses as well), you can disable the tunnel mechanism entirely via `netsh interface ipv6 isatap set state disabled`.

Comment: What is the 192.168.0.10%13 though since I can ping it? Is it a  Device? Actor? Why is it showing up in my firewall log to begin with? What is it that trigger these entries?

Comment: It's your own IP address, isn't it?

Comment: my local ip is 192.168.0.10 not 192.168.0.10%13, I still dont understand what this is, my laptop have the same entries from 192.168.0.10%13

Comment: But that's the exact same address. I wrote in the post that `%13` is the adapter ID – it's an instruction to the OS about _how_ to use the address.

Comment: Ok, What cause it to show up on my computer and also my laptop then? The entries in the firewall doesnt show up systematically (like for a specific time or duration i.e.).

Comment: Usually the ISATAP virtual adapter is present _all the time_ unless disabled. I don't know how exactly Norton's firewall checks for it, but it probably coincides with you connecting to LAN / disconnecting from LAN, since that's when you gain / lose the IPv4 address.

Comment: I dont think that is it, because I dont see the entries at every connection/disconnection from the LAN.